# требование заполнения формы полностью

Tags: javascript, css, form

имеется форма и код, который изменяет `input`, если он пустой, как сделать, чтобы заполненное поле возвращалось в исходное состояние с начальными стилями, а пустое оставалось в состоянии стилей как не заполненное

```js
var btn_1 = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn_1.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    document.querySelectorAll('.input_1').forEach((el) =>
    {  
       let inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.input_1'));
       let inputsValueTrue = inputs.every((input) => input.value);
        if (!inputsValueTrue) {
            el.classList.add('is-required');
            el.placeholder = "Заполните поле";
        } else {
            document.querySelector('form').style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.is-required {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
}

.is-required::placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
      <input type="text" class="input_1">
      <input type="text" class="input_1">
      <button class="btn" type="button">отправить</button>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно на лету отслеживать состояние, но подходит ли вам это?

```js
const btn_1 = document.querySelector('.btn');
const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.input_1'))

inputs.forEach((input) =>
{
  input.addEventListener('input', inputValidate);
})

function inputValidate(e)
{ 
  input = e.target;

  input.classList.toggle('is-required', !input.value);
  input.placeholder = input.value ? "" : "Заполните поле";
}


btn_1.onclick = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  inputs.forEach((input) =>
  {
    inputValidate({target: input});
  });
}
```

```css
.is-required {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
}

.is-required::placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
      <input type="text" class="input_1">
      <input type="text" class="input_1">
      <button class="btn" type="button">отправить</button>  
</form>
```

Comment: даже в примере у тебя не изменяются поля, идею в целом я понял, но можно ли как то немного дополнить то, что имеется?

Comment: В смысле не изменяются?

Comment: нажми **выполнить код** под своим решением

Comment: Нажимал, все работало, кроме кнопки, ее на тот момент не делал. Я отредактировал, теперь по кнопке тоже действия есть.

Comment: я сейчас и у себя и здесь попробовал, ничего не меняется

Comment: Что именно вы пробуете сделать?

Comment: мне нужно сделать доп проверку, т.е. в моём примере даже заполненное поле остаётся с красным `border` и текстом, а мне нужно, чтобы оно менялось

Comment: В моем коде при изменении поля, текст и бордер нормального цвета.

Comment: а, всё, догнал, просто нижнюю часть не увидел. спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: а что делает `target: input`? как именно он работает и что возвращает?

Comment: Он передает объект, где у ключа "target" элемент input'а. Довольно костыльный способ я считаю.

Comment: понял, ещё раз спасибо

Comment: Когда слушатель событий (addEventListener) ловит нужное событие, он передает первым параметром объект event, в котором информация. Из нее нам нужно только target, то есть элемент, на котором произошло событие.

Comment: По нажатию на кнопку вместо ```inputValidate({target: input});``` можно эмулировать событие, но мне кажется это излишнее.